# How to handle IOException and HttpException in Apache HttpClient.execute(HttpMethod)

Tags: httpclient

The documentation (copied below) doesn't say a lot about what IOException and HttpException means in its context.

My question is: after an IOException occurs in a HttpClient.execute(HttpMethod) method, do I have to discard the object and create a new HttpClient in order to execute methods again? Or is it still usable (the HttpClient object) to execute methods after some of these exceptions occur?

```
executeMethod

public int executeMethod(HttpMethod method)
                  throws IOException,
                         HttpException
Executes the given HTTP method.
Parameters:
method - the HTTP method to execute.
Returns:
the method's response code
Throws:
IOException - If an I/O (transport) error occurs. Some transport exceptions can be recovered from.
HttpException - If a protocol exception occurs. Usually protocol exceptions cannot be recovered from.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reuse the `HttpClient` object as many times as you want.  I'm working with version 3.0, and cannot speak to whether or not this has changed in more recent versions.

In regard to the exceptions, the comments are directed more at the `HttpMethod` than the client.

What it means by, "Some transport exceptions can be recovered from", is that you may be able to resend the request and get a valid response.  `IOExceptions` tend to happen when you can't send a request or do not receive a response from the server (e.g. the server is down, or it cannot handle all the requests it is receiving).

What it means by, "Usually protocol exceptions cannot be recovered from", is that the server you're making an HTTP request to is not sending a response that meets the HTTP protocol(s). Usually, resending the request will not yield a different result.

I realize this answer is probably a little late to be useful to you, but future readers may still benefit.

This is [a useful guide on exception handling](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/exception-handling.html) with HttpClient (legacy versions anyway).  It may move around, so here's a [useful search](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahc.apache.org+exception+handling) for finding the page.